Disable eslint rules for recommended rules without ignorefile
I have a eslint.config.js file like this:
import js from "@eslint/js";

export default [
  js.configs.recommended,
  {
    files: ["**/*.{js,jsx}"],
    ignores: ["**/node_modules/*", ".git/*", "wwwroot/build/*"],
    rules: {...}
  }
];

The ignores attribute unfortunately only refers to my own rules, not to the js.configs.recommended ones. Is there a way to do this without adding an ignorefile?

It happens as it always does: 10 minutes after I asked the question, I found the answer in the docs.
You can set global ignore when ignores is used without any other keys in the configuration object.
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#globally-ignoring-files-with-ignores
import js from "@eslint/js";

export default [
  {
    ignores: ["**/node_modules/*", ".git/*", "wwwroot/build/*"]
  };
  js.configs.recommended,
  {
    files: ["**/*.{js,jsx}"],
    rules: {...}
  }
];

